# custom page in magento

Tags: magento

I want to make a page where I can write my custom code.

I want to place the link shopping cart (where card detail is shown). How can I do this, is there any specific method or must I change the core files?

Please guide me.

Comment: I've tried to make your question a little clearer but I still don't understand "link shopping cart (where card detail is shown)".

Answer (score 1):

Adding new pages requires a custom module, please refer to [the development knowledge base](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/categories/category/development/).

You will need:

- A controller to deliver the new page and perform actions.
- A layout file which defines handles to match each action in your controller.
- Templates as required by the layout.
- Possibly blocks which contain your custom code (the display logic) and which are rendered by the templates.
- Patience.

Answer (score 0):

By the way I see it, you want to add a link to an area in the checkout area.

First, you must find the file which you will need to modify.

There is a handy way of finding out which file you need to modify by turning on something called Template Path Hints.

There's a handy video here: http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/template-path-hints-tutorial-video/ that shows you how to turn it on and how to use it.

After that, all you need to do is find the appropriate template file, and add any code you need to it.

Also, make sure that if the file that you need is not in your theme's folder, copy it from the default/default or base/default location to the relevant folder in your themes dafault/[yourthemesnamehere] location.